# StringType issue: Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType@

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

```java
@Override
public Option<DataType> getCatalystType(int sqlType, String typeName, int size, MetadataBuilder md) {
    switch (sqlType) {
    case java.sql.Types.JAVA_OBJECT:
        switch (typeName) {
        case "map(varchar(2147483647),varchar(2147483647))":
            return Option.apply(DataTypes.createMapType(new StringType(), new StringType()));               
        }
        break;
    }
    return super.getCatalystType(sqlType, typeName, size, md);      
}
```

Code is used to support complex data type when return `JAVA_OBJECT`. This same code, I have written in Scala which is working fine. But when use the above code in Java, It is giving:

`Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType@582b14e2 (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType).`

---

Scala code for reference:

```scala
override def getCatalystType(sqlType: Int, typeName: String, size: Int, md: MetadataBuilder): Option[DataType] = sqlType match {
    case java.sql.Types.JAVA_OBJECT =>
      typeName match {
        case "map(varchar(2147483647),varchar(2147483647))" => Option(DataTypes.createMapType(StringType, StringType))
        case "BIT" => Option(BooleanType)
        case _ => None
      }
    case _ => None
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the singleton **`DataTypes.StringType`** instead *([as recommended](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StringType.html#StringType--)):*

```
...
...(DataTypes.createMapType(DataTypes.StringType, DataTypes.StringType))
```

---

> *The data type representing String values. Please use the singleton
> **DataTypes.StringType**.*

Comment: Saved my day!! As a Spark noob, there was no way I would've figured this out that intuitively.